# Gitlab - Check file content with pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I'm creating a `pipeline` for manage `Wordpress` themes building and I need to make sure that when a user merge the code on the `master branch` the theme version is different from the one already present in master.

For example I have in master the `1.0.0` version, I want to make sure that after the merge the version is greather (or at least different ) from 1.0.0.

This is my stage:

```
check_theme_version_number:
  stage: checks
  script:
    - git fetch
    - lines=$(git diff origin/master origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME -- wp-content/themes/$THEME_NAME/style.css | grep Version | wc -l)
    - if (($lines == 0)); then exit 1; fi
  only:
    - master
```

`$THEME_NAME` is passed from Gitlab variables.

When I run this stage I get:

```
$ git fetch
From https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx
 * [new branch]      develop    -> origin/develop
$ lines=$(git diff origin/master origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME -- wp-content/themes/$THEME_NAME/style.css | grep Version | wc -l)
fatal: bad revision 'origin/'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```